# Adding `href` to Card component makes all text inside uppercase

Tags: semantic-ui-react

Adding `href` to semantic-ui-react Card component makes all text inside this component uppercase. How to avoid it?

Comment: I do not know for sure, but probably a text-transform in css ? What have you tried to debug ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai text is dynamically changing so i cant just make text-transform to something, i just wanna make it appear as it comes in props, but making Card component as a link makes all text uppercase

Comment: I said, it could be a simple css property which has been applied on the card title, I cannot know for sure though. If it is because of css, you could overwrite the "text-transform" property to avoid the uppercase

Comment: @DhananjaiPai thx, didn't understand u at first, overwriting text-transform to none worked for me

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer below, if it worked. Might help others who come with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be because of the "text-transform" css property.
Setting it to none, should fix the issue.